# FFImageLoading: How to add authentication?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, ffimageloading

I'm trying to use [FFImageLoading](https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading/wiki) in my Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android apps to load images from url. All the url's require authentication..

Also I'm using `modernhttpclient` for all other Rest Calls. For `modernhttpclient` this is how I'm adding authentication

```
var cookieHandler = new NativeCookieHandler ();
var messageHandler = new NativeMessageHandler (false, false, cookieHandler);
cookieHandler.SetCookies (RestApiPaths.cookies);
using (var client = new HttpClient (messageHandler)) {
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation ("User-Agent", GetUserAgent (platform));
var r = await client.GetAsync (new Uri (url));
```

and it is working very well. I did same thing for FFImageLoading,

```
var cookieHandler = new NativeCookieHandler ();
var messageHandler = new NativeMessageHandler (false, false, cookieHandler);
cookieHandler.SetCookies (RestApiPaths.cookies);
var client = new HttpClient (messageHandler);
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation ("User-Agent", RestApiPaths.GetUserAgent (Constants.__IOS__));

ImageService.Instance.Initialize (new Configuration {
    HttpClient = client
});

ImageService.Instance.LoadUrl (url).Into (ArticleImageView);
```

but unfortunately, it is not working. No image get loaded. I know it is problem with authentication. I tried with another url which does not require authentication and its working. Can someone please tell what should I do to get it working.

**EDIT:**

I tried this from [Authentication-Support](https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading/wiki/Authentication-Support)

```
public class AuthenticatedHttpImageClientHandler : HttpClientHandler
{

    public AuthenticatedHttpImageClientHandler()
    {

    }

    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        request.Headers.Add("Cookie", RestApiPaths.cookie);
        request.Headers.Add("User-Agent", RestApiPaths.GetUserAgent(Constants.__IOS__));
        return await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
}
```

then:

```
ImageService.Instance.Initialize (new Configuration {
    HttpClient = new HttpClient(new AuthenticatedHttpImageClientHandler())
});
```

but still not working..

Comment: Have you checked this document: [Authentication Support](https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading/wiki/Authentication-Support)? Seems like you need to create your own handler for adding token and use this handler in `HttpClient`.

Comment: @GraceFeng-MSFT please see my edit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's how I did it

```
ImageService.Instance.Initialize(new Configuration {
    HttpClient = NetworkHelper.GetAuthenticatedHttpClient(Constants.__IOS__)
});
ImageService.Instance.LoadUrl(url).Into(imageView);
```

NetworkHelper.GetAuthenticatedHttpClient returns the an HttpClient with the required headers and auth token in my case.

```
public static HttpClient GetAuthenticatedHttpClient(int platform)
{
     HttpClient client = new HttpClient(messageHandler);
     client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("User-Agent", GetUserAgent(platform));
     client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("X-Time-Zone", timezone);
     client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("appVersion", CommonHelper.AppVersion);
     client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("X-Auth", GetAuthToken());
     return client;
}
```

You only have to do `Instance.Initialize` only once

Comment: For me the problem was the User-Agent header.

Comment: How would I do it if I have to change the header Host for each url? The domain is different on each url.