# How to set User Agent to the headers of Xamarin views?

Tags: c#, xamarin, header, user-agent

I have a web instance with some rules for blocking suspect requests and it's blocking all requests from my xamarin project. Server returns status code Forbidden and when I get the details the cause is "**NoUserAgent_HEADER**".

I had same problem with WebClient requests and solve that by adding `webclient.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)");` but how to solve that in requests coming from xaml?

**Update**

For example: 
`<Image Source="https...." />` this is being blocked!

Comment: do you mean an XF WebView control?

Comment: @Jason No... an image, for example: <Image source="https....." />. I updated the question with this information, sorry for missing that.

Comment: there are many existing questions that address similar issues - I'd suggest using FFImageloading, OR simply disabling the rules for image requests.  See https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading/wiki/Authentication-Support#custom-authentication--headers

Comment: @Jason I just noticed that when setting image with Binding it works, but if set xImageName.Source="..." it doesn't works. I'm migrating everything to bind.

Comment: @Jason it means that xamarin already sets an header, right?

Comment: @ÉderRochaBezerra There is one thread that you may have help:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41301212/ffimageloading-how-to-add-authentication